# Module-Federation: How to addEventListener in Shell app for MFEs App Angular element web components

Tags: javascript, angular, webpack-module-federation

I am using Angular v14.1.1 and @angular-architects/module-federation v14.
And In MFEs using `Angular elements`  `createCustomElement` and  exposes as `./web-component` using @angular-architects/module-federation webpack config.
From MFEs app emit event but not getting how to add MFEs listener in shell application to listen event.

for example

**MFEs App**

App.module.ts

```
export class AppModule implements DoBootstrap
{
  constructor(private injector: Injector) { }
  ngDoBootstrap(): void {
    if (!customElements.get('angular14-customer')) {
      customElements.define(
        'angular14-customer',
        createCustomElement(MFEComponent, { injector: this.injector })
      );
    }
  }
 }
```

**Shell App**

AppRoutingModule ts

```
import { WebComponentWrapper, WebComponentWrapperOptions } from '@angular-architects/module-federation-tools';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [ 
{
  path: 'angular14',
  component: WebComponentWrapper,
  data: {
    type:'module',
    remoteEntry: 'http://localhost:4201/remoteEntry.js',
    exposedModule: './web-components',
    elementName: 'angular14-customer'
  } as WebComponentWrapperOptions
}];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

**For example MFEs Component Event:**

```
@Output() saveRecord: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();

MFESaveClick(response){
 this.saveRecord.emit(response);
}
```

How to add Event Listener in Shell app for MFES Events?

Please let me know if any other detail required.

please advise.

Thanks.

Comment: There is not enough information here. How are you firing the events from the remotes? Using @Output on MfeComponent..? Also, why are you using module federation at all..? If you have webcomponents, you can simply add those directly in your ‘host’ app?

Comment: yes using like Output EventEmitter from MfeCOmponent.

Comment: Well… this will is somewhat complicated because you basically have webcomponents inside an Angular shell. So you cannot use the normal angular way of listening to outputs. So in your host, you could use normal querySelectors for your webcomponent element and then do an addEventListener.  You have made it pretty complex for yourself. I’d recommend to either go full MF and federate actual Angular components (then you can use services to communicate) or drop MF and just embed webcomponents. Just my take.

Comment: "why are you using module federation?" I think so to improve MFEs download performance at runtime as I have multi MFEs app and to Utilize shared libs from shell app.

Comment: Did you check you can actually use shared services with the webcomponents? Also, performance wise, using straight up webcomponents with an Angular app is potentially faster. MF adds quite some overhead. However, going full MF (not with Angular elements but with actual angular components that can share stuff) is better than what you have now, performance wise. Every separate webcomponent (through elements) is a full Angular app inside). And MF doesn’t help you to share stuff (because of the WC layer).

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about exact solution but I think there is way using web-components Input/Output `@angular-architects/module-federation-tools` as **Directly Loading a Web Component via Module Federation** menintion [here](https://npm.io/package/@angular-architects/module-federation-tools) in docs.

In shell app creating custom component and route to path by imports `ModuleFederationToolsModule`.

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
     path:'angular14',
     component: CustomerComponent  
  },
  {
    path:'**',component:NotFoundComponent
  }
  ];
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    CustomerComponent,
    NotFoundComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    CommonModule,
   RouterModule.forRoot(routes),
    ModuleFederationToolsModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  schemas:[]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

And then in `CustomerComponent` using `WebComponentWrapper` selector.

for example

```
<mft-wc-wrapper [options]="options" [props]="props" [events]="events"></mft-wc-wrapper>
```

```
import { WebComponentWrapper, WebComponentWrapperOptions } from '@angular-architects/module-federation-tools';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-customer',
  templateUrl: './customer.component.html'
})
export class CustomerComponent {
  title = 'CustomerComponent';
  props = {
    "message": "Hello from Shell"
}

events = {
    "saveRecord": (event:any) => {
        console.debug('saveRecord!', event);
    }
}
  options: WebComponentWrapperOptions = {
    type:'module',
    remoteEntry: 'http://localhost:4201/remoteEntry.js',
    exposedModule: './web-components',
    elementName: 'angular14-customer'
  };
}
```

And remote app you can use props and events something like this.

```
<!--MFEComponent-->
remote app!
<button (click)="MFESaveClick($event)">click me !</button>
```

```
//MFEComponent
 
  @Output() saveRecord: EventEmitter<any>
  = new EventEmitter<any>();

  @Input() message:any;
   

  MFESaveClick(response){
 this.saveRecord.emit(response);
 }
```

Not tested, but hope this will help.

Comment: thanks for the help. Sure let me try this approach..+v1